# In Express.js, how do I make my template display the flash messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('home'); // I want the template to be able to access the flash message..
});

app.get('/go',function(req,res){
    req.flash("info", "You went GO, and got redirected to home!");
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

The user first goes to "/go".  After that, he will be redirected to "/" and I want a flash message to show as a javascript alert.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add it as a local to your call to render:

```
res.render("home", {info: req.flash("info")});
```

And use it in your template:

```
#flash
  p= info
```

Comment: Well that sucks. Requires to define info for every single template `render` call :/

Comment: You can use dynamicHelpers to pass the data directly to the view on each request

Answer (score 6):

You can use express dynamic helpers to make your life easier.

```
app.dynamicHelpers({flashMessages: function(req, res) {
var html = ""
  , flash  = req.flash();
['error', 'info'].forEach(function(type) {
  if(flash[type]) {
    flash[type].forEach(function(message) {
      html += "<div class='alert " + type + "'>" + message + "</div>";
    });
  }
});
return html; }});
```

and in your layout (ejs example)

```
  <body><%- flashMessages %><%- body %></body>
```

Comment: using a dynamic helpers is good idea, but in your example you end up with html in your logic. You should instead `return req.flash` and handle the graphical representation of the data in your view

Answer (score 5):

```
app.dynamicHelpers({flash: function(req, res){return req.flash();}});
```

Now you have access at the flash object in you view. No HTML in your logic and no need to add all the params in every routes.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I use the following code to display flash message:

In **app.js**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 req.session.message = req.session.message || { error: [], success: [], info: [] };
 app.locals.message  = req.session.message;
}
```

In your **user.js** route:

```
app.post('/users/new', function (req, res, next) {
    //...
    // do some work
    req.session.message.info.push('Account created successfully');
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

Then, create a `message.jade` in view that you could be included into other views:

In **message.jade**

```
- var i
- if (message.error && message.error.length)
  .alert.alert-warning.alert-dismissable
    button.close(type="button", data-dismiss="alert", aria-hidden="true") &times;
    - for (i = 0; i < message.error.length; i++)
      .center!= message.error[i]
- if (message.info && message.info.length)
  .alert.alert-info.alert-dismissable
    button.close(type="button", data-dismiss="alert", aria-hidden="true") &times;
    - for (i = 0; i < message.info.length; i++)
      .center!= message.info[i]
- message.info = message.error = [] // REMEMBER to reset messages to an empty array
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue, solution seems to be:

```
req.flash('error', 'validation failed');
res.redirect('back');
```

Using back seems to maintain the flash message, where as redirecting to the same route looses it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Express 3, the built-in flash functionality has been removed. To get the same functionality, you'll want to install the `connect-flash` module, then add the code from this Gist just after you initialize your sessions and before `app.use(app.router);`: https://gist.github.com/3070950